# Erro ao gravar e ler arquivo em CSV

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Estou com o seguinte problema na gravação de um arquivo em CSV. O arquivo aparece desse jeito:

> NULL

**Minha classe de Arquivo**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;

    public class Arquivo {


        private String conteudo;

        private BufferedReader leitor;


        public static void Gravar(String conteudo) {

            try{  

                File diretorio = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Teste_Excel\\teste");
                BufferedWriter escrever = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(diretorio + "arquivoNomes.txt",true));
                escrever.append(conteudo + "\n");
                escrever.newLine();
                escrever.flush();
                escrever.close();
            }  

            catch(IOException e){  
                System.out.println("Erro na gravação do arquivo: "+ e.getMessage());  
            }  
        }

        public String Ler(String caminho) {

            String texto = "";

            try {
                Reader arquivo = new InputStreamReader(new  FileInputStream(caminho), "UTF-8");
                leitor = new BufferedReader(arquivo); 

                 while((texto = leitor.readLine()) != null){
                    this.setConteudo(texto);
                    System.out.println(this.getConteudo());
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro na leitura do arquivo: "+ e.getMessage());  
            }

            return this.conteudo;
        }

        public void setConteudo(String conteudo) {
            this.conteudo = conteudo;
        }

        public String getConteudo() {
            return this.conteudo;
        }

    }
```

**Minha classe Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Arquivo aq = new Arquivo();
        String caminho = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Teste_Excel\\p1.xlsx";
        String conteudo = aq.getConteudo();


        aq.Ler(caminho);
        aq.Gravar(conteudo);
    }


}
```

Comment: Já tentou salvar o arquivo em CSV para testar se o erro ocorre também?

Comment: @R.Santosc Sim o arquivo aparece com null, na célula.

Comment: Tente alterar essa linha `BufferedWriter escrever = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(diretorio + "arquivoNomes.txt",true));` por isso `BufferedWriter strW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(diretorio + "arquivoNomes.txt",true), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));`

Comment: Aparece com null.

Comment: Excel tem o formato dele, não é simplesmente ler como um arquivo de texto. Pode-se utilizar uma biblioteca como a [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) para ler e manipular o arquivo.

Comment: @Renan Realmente você tem razão, porém o script acima não esta funcionado nem para arquivos csv.

Comment: Tente ler o arquivo `xlsx` assim: `Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\testes\\teste.xls"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        int linhas = sheet.getRows();`

Comment: @R.Santos não estou usando libs externas como a jexcel api.

Comment: Você conseguiu ver se a leitura esta te retornando algo?

Comment: @R.Santos A leitura sim agora o gravação continua retornando `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas é o comportamento esperado, não?! Você está escrevendo `null` no arquivo. Basta acompanhar como você está chamando os métodos dentro da classe `Main`:

- Instanciou um objeto `Arquivo`.
- Criou uma variável `caminho` e deu a ela um valor.
- Obteve `null` ao chamar `aq.getConteudo();`, afinal, o método `Arquivo#Ler()` que é responsável por modificar o valor do atributo `Arquivo#conteudo` não foi chamado. Aqui, `Main#conteudo` é `null`.
- Chamou `aq.Ler(caminho);` e não fez nada com o valor de retorno (nem com o atributo `conteudo`).
- Gravou o valor de `Main#conteudo` no arquivo. Lembra que ele era `null`? **:)**

Teu código deveria ser executado assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Arquivo aq = new Arquivo();
        String caminho = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Teste_Excel\\p1.xlsx";

        aq.Ler(caminho);
        String conteudo = aq.getConteudo();

        aq.Gravar(conteudo);
    }
}
```

Ou então:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Arquivo aq = new Arquivo();
        String caminho = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Teste_Excel\\p1.xlsx";

        String conteudo = aq.Ler(caminho);
        aq.Gravar(conteudo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente! Obrigado pela ajuda.